# What is right way to accept a lot of requests with Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My app controller accepts requests from third party API (webhooks), but when it becomes 400 RPM my site goes down (too many clients). What can I do with it?

```
class CallbacksController < ApplicationController
def acceptor
    if params['type'] == 'confirmation' # this type is rare. only when client switches on callback
      group_setting = GroupSetting.find_by_callback_token(params[:callback_token])
      if group_setting
        group_setting.update_attribute(:use_callback, true)
        GroupSetting.new.callback_start(group_setting.group, group_setting.user)
        render text: group_setting.response_string
      else
        render text:'ok'
      end
    else
      CallbackWorker.perform_async(params[:callback_token], params['type'],
                                       params['group_id'], params['object'],
                                       params['secret'])
      render text:'ok'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a web server thread bottleneck. Could you specify which server are you using? Can you make an [Apache Benchmark](http://work.stevegrossi.com/2015/02/07/load-testing-rails-apps-with-apache-bench-siege-and-jmeter/) and post the results? Maybe a little more information on your setup could help.

If you are using WEBrick, I would advise trying with [PUMA](http://puma.io/).

I would also suggest that you check out [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) that integrates easily with NGINX or [Unicorn](http://bogomips.org/unicorn/), that can help you with load balancing your requests.

Comment: maybe you are right. my case is Passenger + Nginx. I know that Passenger has limit of max connections = 100, but before it starts to block new site visitors, the site becomes very slow. So what to show in my case?